# Анимация разрезания досок дисковой пилой

Tags: html, вёрстка, svg, svg-animation

Есть [топик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1146640/28748), в котором реализована анимация вращения и движения дисковой пилы

```css
html {
  background-color: #337ab7;
}

.cutline {
  stroke: #222;
  stroke-width: .1%;
  stroke-width: .5%;
  stroke-dasharray: 1% 2%;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  fill: none;
}

.sawblade {
  fill: #eee;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 3387 1270">
  <path id="cutline" class="cutline" d="M 2700 1000 L 100 1000 " />
<g class="sawblade" >
  <path id="sawblade" d="M779.9,413.8s15.26,-47.61,-89.24,-73.22c-1.24,-0.3,-2.45,-0.58,-3.65,-0.84c20.57,-19,50.83,-37.45,85.5,-28.49c0,0,2.29,-50,-105.27,-47.38c-1.2,0,-2.36,0.08,-3.51,0.13c14.95,-23.6,39.28,-49.18,74.95,-49.6c0,0,-10.8,-48.82,-114,-18.32l-1.63,0.49c8.62,-26.2,25.66,-55.9,59.27,-65.14c0,0,-22.88,-44.46,-114.87,11.33c-1.1,0.66,-2.15,1.32,-3.18,2c1.12,-28,9.45,-62.41,40.3,-80.6c0,0,-33.69,-36.94,-107.93,40.94c-0.82,0.87,-1.62,1.72,-2.39,2.57c-6.15,-27.25,-7,-62.55,18,-88.07c0,0,-42.16,-26.89,-93.55,67.63c-0.27,0.51,-0.53,1,-0.8,1.5c-12.43,-24.62,-21.38,-57.66,-4.15,-88c0,0,-47.61,-15.25,-73.22,89.24c-0.3,1.24,-0.58,2.46,-0.84,3.65c-19,-20.57,-37.45,-50.82,-28.49,-85.49c0,0,-50,-2.3,-47.38,105.26c0,1.2,0.08,2.37,0.13,3.52c-23.62,-14.93,-49.18,-39.29,-49.56,-75c0,0,-48.82,10.79,-18.32,114c0.16,0.55,0.32,1.09,0.49,1.62c-26.2,-8.61,-55.9,-25.66,-65.14,-59.27c0,0,-44.46,22.88,11.33,114.88q1,1.64,2,3.18c-28,-1.12,-62.42,-9.46,-80.6,-40.31c0,0,-36.94,33.7,40.94,107.93c0.86,0.83,1.72,1.62,2.57,2.4c-27.25,6.15,-62.55,7,-88.07,-18c0,0,-26.89,42.15,67.63,93.54l1.5,0.8c-24.62,12.44,-57.66,21.38,-88,4.15c0,0,-15.26,47.62,89.24,73.22c1.24,0.31,2.46,0.58,3.65,0.85c-20.57,19,-50.82,37.44,-85.49,28.49c0,0,-2.3,49.94,105.26,47.37c1.2,0,2.37,-0.07,3.52,-0.13c-14.93,23.63,-39.29,49.19,-75,49.57c0,0,10.79,48.82,114,18.32l1.62,-0.5c-8.61,26.21,-25.66,55.9,-59.27,65.14c0,0,22.88,44.46,114.88,-11.32c1.09,-0.67,2.15,-1.33,3.18,-2c-1.12,28,-9.46,62.42,-40.31,80.6c0,0,33.7,36.94,107.93,-40.93c0.83,-0.87,1.62,-1.73,2.4,-2.58c6.15,27.26,7,62.56,-18,88.07c0,0,42.15,26.89,93.54,-67.63c0.28,-0.51,0.54,-1,0.8,-1.5c12.44,24.62,21.38,57.67,4.15,88c0,0,47.62,15.26,73.22,-89.24c0.31,-1.24,0.58,-2.45,0.85,-3.65c19,20.57,37.44,50.83,28.49,85.5c0,0,49.94,2.29,47.37,-105.27c0,-1.2,-0.07,-2.36,-0.13,-3.51c23.63,14.92,49.18,39.28,49.57,75c0,0,48.82,-10.8,18.32,-114c-0.16,-0.55,-0.33,-1.09,-0.5,-1.63c26.21,8.62,55.9,25.66,65.14,59.27c0,0,44.46,-22.88,-11.32,-114.87c-0.67,-1.1,-1.33,-2.15,-2,-3.18c28,1.12,62.42,9.46,80.6,40.31c0,0,36.94,-33.7,-40.93,-107.94c-0.87,-0.82,-1.73,-1.62,-2.58,-2.39c27.26,-6.15,62.56,-7,88.07,18c0,0,26.89,-42.16,-67.63,-93.55l-1.5,-0.8c24.69,-12.4,57.74,-21.35,88.04,-4.12zm-442.7,-23.46a53.14,53.14,0,1,1,53.14,53.14a53.15,53.15,0,0,1,-53.14,-53.14z" >
    <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="360 390.35 390.35; 0 390.35 390.35" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animateTransform>
    <animateMotion dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto" >
    <mpath xlink:href="#cutline" />
    </animateMotion> 
  </path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

В этом вопросе решалась задача одновременной двойной анимации: вращения и перемещения.
Но пример  выглядит не вполне реалистично. Хочется сделать, что-то более реальное.
Например разрезание досок на две половины вдоль.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но всё оказалось не так просто.  При размещении кода, доски и пилы, либо доска заслоняла пилу, либо пила была на первом плане, загораживая доску. А нужно, чтобы пила врезалась в доску, была видна линия реза и после прохождения пилы получилось бы две половинки доски.
Пробовал всякие решения с помощью `clip-path`, `mask` и т.д, чтобы скрывать ненужные части изображения.

Как реализовать данную задачу?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Пожалуй сделаю на CSS)

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.woods-area {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.-l,
.-r {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  animation: 6.6s 5.2s linear forwards;
}

.-l {
  width: 0%;
  animation-name: wood-moveSaw--l;
}

.-r {
  width: 100%;
  animation-name: wood-moveSaw--r;
}

.-l .-wrap {
  left: 0;
}

.-r .-wrap {
  right: 0;
}

.-wrap {
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.wood-area {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wood {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 12px;
  background: #d3a76f;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow:
    -1px -1px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.35) inset,
    1px 1px 1px -1px rgba(255,255,255,.85) inset;
}

.wood::before,
.wood::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow:
    -1px -1px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.35) inset,
    1px 1px 1px -1px rgba(255,255,255,.85) inset;
}

.wood::before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #d3a76f, #eac18b);
  transform: 
    skewX(-50deg)
    translate(9px, .5px);
  bottom: 100%;
}

.wood::after {
  width: 17px;
  height: 14px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #d3a76f, #eac18b);
  left: 100%;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: 
    skewY(-37deg)
    translate(-.5px, -2px);
}

.wood-area:nth-child(1) {
  padding-left: 14px;
}

.wood-area:nth-child(2) {
  padding-top: 0px;
  width: calc(100% - 16px);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

.-l .wood-area:nth-child(2) {
  position: relative;
  animation: wood-drop--r .65s 11.5s linear forwards;
}

.-r .wood-area:nth-child(1) .wood::before {
  box-shadow:
    1px 1px 1px -1px rgba(255,255,255,.85) inset;
}

.-r .wood-area:nth-child(2) .wood::before {
  box-shadow:
    -1px -1px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.35) inset;
}

.-r .wood-area .wood::before {
  background-size: auto 200%;
}

.-r .wood-area:nth-child(1) .wood::before {
  background-position: top center;
}

.-r .wood-area:nth-child(2) .wood::before {
  background-position: bottom center;
}

.-r .wood-area .wood::after {
  background-size: 200% auto;
}

.-r .wood-area:nth-child(1) .wood::after {
  background-position: right center;
}

.-r .wood-area:nth-child(2) .wood::after {
  background-position: left center;
}

.-r .wood-area:nth-child(1) .wood::after {
  box-shadow:
    -1px -1px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.35) inset,
    0px 1px 1px -1px rgba(255,255,255,.85) inset;
}

.-r .wood-area:nth-child(2) .wood::after {
  box-shadow:
    0px -1px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.35) inset,
    1px 1px 1px -1px rgba(255,255,255,.85) inset;
}

.cir-saw {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/vZytwaX.png') no-repeat center center / 100% auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 12px;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  z-index: 5;
  animation:
    startSaw 4s cubic-bezier(.5,0,.75,0) forwards,
    turnSaw .1s 4s linear infinite,
    moveSaw 10s 5s linear forwards,
    startSaw 4s 15s cubic-bezier(.25,1,.5,1) forwards;
  z-index: 2;
}

.shavings {
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 60px;
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/8tReYJE.png') repeat-y center top / 100% auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 70px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotate(15deg);
  animation: 
    shavings-anim .2s linear infinite,
    shavings-visible 5.6s 5.6s linear forwards,
    moveSaw 10s 5s linear forwards;
}

.shavings::before,
.shavings::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  background: inherit;
  transform-origin: top right;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 15%;
}

.shavings::before {
  transform: rotate(7.5deg);
  z-index: 2;
}

.shavings::after {
  transform: rotate(15deg);
  z-index: 3;
}

.shavings-down {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/ErX5QSt.png') repeat-x left bottom / auto 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 78px;
  left: -32px;
}

.shavings-down::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
  background: inherit;
  margin-left: -16px;
}

@keyframes startSaw {
  0% {transform: translate(0, -50%) rotate(0deg);}
  100% {transform: translate(0, -50%) rotate(1080deg);}
}

@keyframes turnSaw {
  0% {transform: translate(0, -50%) rotate(0deg);}
  100% {transform: translate(0, -50%) rotate(360deg);}
}

@keyframes moveSaw {
  0% {left: 0;}
  100% {left: 100%;}
}

@keyframes wood-moveSaw--l {
  0% {width: 0%;}
  100% {width: 100%;}
}

@keyframes wood-moveSaw--r {
  0% {width: 100%;}
  100% {width: 0%;}
}

@keyframes wood-drop--r {
  0% {
    margin-top: 0;
    transform-origin: top left;
  }
  45% {transform: rotate(-15deg);}
  0%, 50%, 100% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
  50%, 100% {margin-top: 50px;}
}

@keyframes shavings-anim {
  0% {background-position: center 0%;}
  100% {background-position: center 100%;}
}

@keyframes shavings-visible {
  0%, 99.99% {opacity: 1;}
  100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="woods-area">
  <div class="-l">
    <div class="-wrap">
      <div class="wood-area">
        <div class="wood"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="wood-area">
        <div class="wood"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="shavings-down"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="-r">
    <div class="-wrap">
      <div class="wood-area">
        <div class="wood"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="wood-area">
        <div class="wood"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cir-saw"></div>
  <div class="shavings"></div>
</div>
```

Только этими палками не бейте)

Comment: отличный ответ Денис, мне очень понравилось всё, особенно опилки! :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, спасибо. По-моему самое ужасное это опилки :D

Comment: главное, что опилки есть :D  Можно сделать их более реалистичными, используя фильтры, патерны, маски, но это при желании конечно. Может попробуешь ответить [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1147300/28748) взять за основу и проявить фантазию, всплывающие пузырьки например или ещё что-нибудь

Comment: Ох.. Интересно, попробую)

Answer (score 11):

Нужно закодировать две половинки доски и одну разместить перед пилой, а вторую половинку доски поместить за пилой. Таким образом получается, что пила врезается в доску.

При перемещении пилы за ней тянется линия реза, которая реализуется анимацией увеличения линии

```
<line x1="820" y1="580" x2="820" y2="580" stroke="black" stroke-width="16" >
           <!-- Анимация появления разреза -->
          <animate id="cut_line" attributeName="x2" begin="svg1.click" dur="10s" values="828;3550" />
```

В конце анимации реза половинки доски падают

```
<animateTransform id="an_fell"
         attributeType="xml"
         attributeName="transform"
         type="translate"
         values="0 0; 120 550"
         begin="cut_line.end"
         dur="1s"
         repeatCount="1"
         fill="freeze"
         additive="sum" />
```

*Анимация начинается после клика по холсту SVG*

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 3387 1270" version="1.1">
<g id="g906" transform="translate(400,126)">
<path id="path846"
   d="M 514.46257,288.68093 H 3267.7437 l -111.1614,192.53728 -2748.7345,0 z"
   style="fill:#e4c000;stroke:black;stroke-width:4" />
<path  id="path900"
   d="M 403.30112,481.21821 H 3156.5823 l 111.1614,-192.53728 3.3199,85.72051 -106.2504,184.03106 -2756.9654,0.25024 z"
   style="fill:#e4c000;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:4;" />  
<!-- Анимация падения доски -->
   <animateTransform id="an_fell2"
 attributeType="xml"
 attributeName="transform"
 type="translate"
 values="0 0; 0 350"
 begin="an_fell.begin + 0.8s "
 dur="1s"
 repeatCount="1"
 fill="freeze"
 additive="sum" />     
   
  </g>

<g transform="translate(50,126)"
 id="g4">
<path
   id="sawblade"
   d="m 779.9,413.8 c 0,0 15.26,-47.61 -89.24,-73.22 -1.24,-0.3 -2.45,-0.58 -3.65,-0.84 20.57,-19 50.83,-37.45 85.5,-28.49 0,0 2.29,-50 -105.27,-47.38 -1.2,0 -2.36,0.08 -3.51,0.13 14.95,-23.6 39.28,-49.18 74.95,-49.6 0,0 -10.8,-48.82 -114,-18.32 l -1.63,0.49 c 8.62,-26.2 25.66,-55.9 59.27,-65.14 0,0 -22.88,-44.46 -114.87,11.33 -1.1,0.66 -2.15,1.32 -3.18,2 1.12,-28 9.45,-62.41 40.3,-80.6 0,0 -33.69,-36.94 -107.93,40.94 -0.82,0.87 -1.62,1.72 -2.39,2.57 -6.15,-27.25 -7,-62.55 18,-88.07 0,0 -42.16,-26.89 -93.55,67.63 -0.27,0.51 -0.53,1 -0.8,1.5 -12.43,-24.62 -21.38,-57.66 -4.15,-88 0,0 -47.61,-15.25 -73.22,89.24 -0.3,1.24 -0.58,2.46 -0.84,3.65 -19,-20.57 -37.45,-50.82 -28.49,-85.49 0,0 -50,-2.3 -47.38,105.26 0,1.2 0.08,2.37 0.13,3.52 -23.62,-14.93 -49.18,-39.29 -49.56,-75 0,0 -48.82,10.79 -18.32,114 0.16,0.55 0.32,1.09 0.49,1.62 -26.2,-8.61 -55.9,-25.66 -65.14,-59.27 0,0 -44.46,22.88 11.33,114.88 q 1,1.64 2,3.18 c -28,-1.12 -62.42,-9.46 -80.6,-40.31 0,0 -36.94,33.7 40.94,107.93 0.86,0.83 1.72,1.62 2.57,2.4 -27.25,6.15 -62.55,7 -88.07,-18 0,0 -26.89,42.15 67.63,93.54 l 1.5,0.8 c -24.62,12.44 -57.66,21.38 -88,4.15 0,0 -15.26,47.62 89.24,73.22 1.24,0.31 2.46,0.58 3.65,0.85 -20.57,19 -50.82,37.44 -85.49,28.49 0,0 -2.3,49.94 105.26,47.37 1.2,0 2.37,-0.07 3.52,-0.13 -14.93,23.63 -39.29,49.19 -75,49.57 0,0 10.79,48.82 114,18.32 l 1.62,-0.5 c -8.61,26.21 -25.66,55.9 -59.27,65.14 0,0 22.88,44.46 114.88,-11.32 1.09,-0.67 2.15,-1.33 3.18,-2 -1.12,28 -9.46,62.42 -40.31,80.6 0,0 33.7,36.94 107.93,-40.93 0.83,-0.87 1.62,-1.73 2.4,-2.58 6.15,27.26 7,62.56 -18,88.07 0,0 42.15,26.89 93.54,-67.63 0.28,-0.51 0.54,-1 0.8,-1.5 12.44,24.62 21.38,57.67 4.15,88 0,0 47.62,15.26 73.22,-89.24 0.31,-1.24 0.58,-2.45 0.85,-3.65 19,20.57 37.44,50.83 28.49,85.5 0,0 49.94,2.29 47.37,-105.27 0,-1.2 -0.07,-2.36 -0.13,-3.51 23.63,14.92 49.18,39.28 49.57,75 0,0 48.82,-10.8 18.32,-114 -0.16,-0.55 -0.33,-1.09 -0.5,-1.63 26.21,8.62 55.9,25.66 65.14,59.27 0,0 44.46,-22.88 -11.32,-114.87 -0.67,-1.1 -1.33,-2.15 -2,-3.18 28,1.12 62.42,9.46 80.6,40.31 0,0 36.94,-33.7 -40.93,-107.94 -0.87,-0.82 -1.73,-1.62 -2.58,-2.39 27.26,-6.15 62.56,-7 88.07,18 0,0 26.89,-42.16 -67.63,-93.55 l -1.5,-0.8 c 24.69,-12.4 57.74,-21.35 88.04,-4.12 z M 337.2,390.34 a 53.14,53.14 0 1 1 53.14,53.14 53.15,53.15 0 0 1 -53.14,-53.14 z">
<!-- Анимация вращения пилы         -->
<animateTransform
 attributeType="xml"
 attributeName="transform"
 type="rotate"
 values="0 390.35 390.35; 360 390.35 390.35"
 dur="2.5s"
 begin="svg1.click"
 repeatCount="indefinite"
 additive="sum" /> 
   <!-- Анимация перемещения пилы -->
  <animateMotion
   dur="15s"
   begin="svg1.click"
   repeatCount="1"
   fill="freeze">
  <mpath xlink:href="#cut" />
  </animateMotion>
</path> 
  </g>     
  
   <g id="g907" transform="translate(303,300)">
<path id="path846"
   d="M 514.46257,288.68093 H 3267.7437 l -111.1614,192.53728 -2748.7345,0 z"
   style="fill:#e4c000;stroke:black;stroke-width:4;" />
<path  id="path900"
   d="M 403.30112,481.21821 H 3156.5823 l 111.1614,-192.53728 3.3199,85.72051 -106.2504,184.03106 -2756.9654,0.25024 z"
   style="fill:#e4c000;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:4;" /> 
<!-- Анимация падения доски -->
   <animateTransform id="an_fell"
 attributeType="xml"
 attributeName="transform"
 type="translate"
 values="0 0; 120 400"
 begin="cut_line.end"
 dur="1s"
 repeatCount="1"
 fill="freeze"
 additive="sum" />     
  </g>  
  <!-- Маскирующая черта -->
<path id="path914" transform="translate(410,108)"
 style="fill:none;stroke:#E4C000;stroke-width:12px;"
 d="M 403.30112,481.21821 H 3156.5823" >
   <animate id="opacity_line2" attributeName="stroke-opacity" begin="an_fell.begin" dur="0.1s" values="1;0" fill="freeze" />
   </path>
 
   <path id="cut" fill="red" d="M10 126 L3500 126"/>
  
<line x1="820" y1="580" x2="820" y2="580" stroke="black" stroke-width="12" >
   <!-- Анимация появления разреза -->
  <animate id="cut_line" attributeName="x2" begin="svg1.click" dur="15s" values="828;3550" /> 
     <!-- Анимация исчезновения разреза -->
    <animate id="opacity_line" attributeName="stroke-opacity" begin="an_fell.begin" dur="0.1s" values="1;0" fill="freeze" />
</line>
</svg>
```

[Live Demo](https://codepen.io/Alexandr_T/pen/XWXeLXO)

Comment: Еще бы опилки добавить...

Comment: Поэтому я и написал. Для реалистичного моделирования опилок наверное много кода придется наваять. Наверное придется   тень делать, котрая повторяет неровности случайного валика опилок за пилой. Да, эти проблемы приятней обсуждать, чем реализовывать в коде.

Comment: Ждём опилки! ;-)